# Soap Web service return null value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, soap, service-reference

I want to use a web service for my project and I'm sure web service work properly (I tested in Boomerang - SOAP & REST Client). [Web service link](https://api.n11.com/ws/ProductService.wsdl). But when I try get datas from service, service returns null, empty or 0 values. I think VS add web service reference doesn't work correctly, But couldn't find where the problem is.

```
  static async Task<String> GetProductAsyncN11()
    {

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var port = new N11ProductServiceReference.ProductServicePortClient();
        var requ = new GetProductListRequest();
        requ.auth = new N11ProductServiceReference.Authentication();         
        requ.auth.appKey = "*****";
        requ.auth.appSecret = "*****";
        requ.pagingData = new N11ProductServiceReference.RequestPagingData();
        requ.pagingData.pageSize = 100;
        requ.pagingData.currentPage = 0;
        var list =await port.GetProductListAsync(requ);
        Console.WriteLine(list.GetProductListResponse.products.Rank);
        Console.WriteLine("xx" + list.GetProductListResponse.result.status);
        Console.WriteLine("xx" + list.GetProductListResponse.products.Length);
        foreach (var item in list.GetProductListResponse.products)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.productSellerCode+item.price+item.saleStatus);
        }
        return "n11";
    }
```

Response is here

[image]

Also When I use Boomerang - SOAP & REST Client, here is the  response

[image]

Comment: It didn't error, and some of the properties are populated so it looks like your service is "working". Whether or not the results are accurate is another thing and not answerable with the given information.

Answer (score 1):

Luckly I solve it. When I added service reference, Visual studio changed orders. I rearranged orders and Problem solved.

This is real order(Taken from Boomerang - SOAP & REST Client);

```
          <currencyAmount>51.00</currencyAmount>
                <currencyType>1</currencyType>
                <displayPrice>45.90</displayPrice>
                <isDomestic>false</isDomestic>
                <id>457916487</id>
                <price>51.00</price>
                <productSellerCode>BZRG</productSellerCode>
                <approvalStatus>2</approvalStatus>
                <saleStatus>3</saleStatus>
                <stockItems>
                    <stockItem>
                        <bundle>true</bundle>
                        <currencyAmount>51.00</currencyAmount>
                        <displayPrice>45.90</displayPrice>
                        <optionPrice>51.00</optionPrice>
                        <sellerStockCode>BZRG01BJ</sellerStockCode>
                        <attributes>
                            <attribute>
                                <name>ADET</name>
                                <value>1</value>
                            </attribute>
                            <attribute>
                                <name>RENK</name>
                                <value>BEJ</value>
                            </attribute>
                        </attributes>
                        <id>126921525657</id>
                        <quantity>0</quantity>
                        <version>3</version>
                    </stockItem>
                  ...
                </stockItems>
                <subtitle>Bazerga Lüks Kapı Altı Soğuk Toz Böcek Önleyici</subtitle>
                <title>Bazerga Dekoratif Kapı Altı Rüzgar Önleyici 90 cm Renk Çeşitleri</title>
                <unitInfo/>
```

and This is order which Visual studio create

```
 private long idField;
    
    private string productSellerCodeField;
    
    private string titleField;
    
    private string subtitleField;
    
    private decimal priceField;
    
    private decimal displayPriceField;
    
    private bool isDomesticField;
    
    private string saleStatusField;
    
    private string approvalStatusField;
    
    private ProductSkuList stockItemsField;
    
    private decimal oldPriceField;
    
    private decimal currencyAmountField;
    
    private string currencyTypeField;
```

I changed This sections order numbers

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=4)]
```